# Error in 'get_tagged_response'

Tags: ruby

I've written a little Ruby script to manage my email (save into `.txt`files and remove spam). Here it goes:

```
require 'gmail'

username = 'gmail_username'
password = 'gmail_password'

gmail = Gmail.new(username, password)

# The piece below should save each unread email from website stated
# Into a .txt file on my machine

folder = '/home/alex/MAIL'
gmail.inbox.emails(:unread, from: 'website@work.ua').each do |email|
  File.open(folder + email + '.txt', 'w+') { |f| f.write(email) }
end

# The piece below should remove spam letters

gmail.inbox.emails(:unread, from: 'site@eurolab.ua').each do |email|
  email.delete!
end

gmail.logout
```

But when I try to run it via `$ ruby managemail.rb` it returns me the following error:

```
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/imap.rb:1198:in `get_tagged_response': Unknown command m1mb83666172lbl (Net::IMAP::BadResponseError)
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, so I'm just making it a comment, but reading through the Gmail and Mail gem descriptions it looks like just using `email` in your block is probably not what you want. In the filename you want `email.message_id` or `email.subject` or whatever you want to call your saved emails. Inside `f.write` you want `email.body.decoded`.

Comment: @Iwassink thank you! The problem might be that Gmail blocks any attempt to log in my mail. I've just fixed the script as you've shown, run it and received a letter from Gmail saying that it blocked an attempt to log in.